# Clarifications Needed Regarding Android Studio

Tags: mobile

I want to test a mobile app.

So, I need an emulator.

For that, I want to know, Android Studio is either an Emulator or Simulator for Android mobiles.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio is an IDE for developing android application. Android Studio provides an AVD Manager where you can easily create Virtual Device to test your application without connecting any real device.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio has AVD(Android Virtual Device) which use to create virtual android device which is called Emulator

Answer (score 0):

### What is Android Studio ?

Developer Android Offical site says this about [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/what-is/android-studio)
Android Studio is the official integrated development environment (IDE) for Google's Android operating system, built on JetBrains' IntelliJ IDEA software and designed specifically for Android development.

### Android Virtual Device

If you desire to test your application on different devices with different screen sizes, Operating system versions but you don't have all the devices.
Do not worry :)
Android Studio does provide feature to simulate a real device known as Android Virtual Device.
You can even configure **multiple** virtual devices (AVDs) by providing different software and hardware configuration.

#### Who manages AVDs ?

**AVD Manager**
The AVD Manager provides a graphical user interface in which you can create and manage Android Virtual Devices (AVDs).

Here a decent tutorials for AVD.
[Tutorial to setup Your emulator on Android Studio](https://www.embarcadero.com/starthere/xe5/mobdevsetup/android/en/creating_an_android_emulator.html)